# Freeing space in ubuntu?

Tags: dell, windows-8

During My Installation I have used my whole hard-disk(about 480 GB) for installing Ubuntu removing My Built in Windows 8  . But recently I want to install windows again as I have come to know that My laptop has a touch-screen and I just want to feel that. Is there any way to free up some memory and install windows alongside Ubuntu? [this](http://www.dell.com/support/troubleshooting/us/en/19/Servicetag/JX5XJW1) is my laptop spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question depends on the filesystem you used for your Ubuntu installation. If it's ext*, you can for instance use gparted (from a live-CD) to shrink the Ubuntu partition.

After that you'll probably have to reinstall the bootloader, but if you install Windows, it will overwrite the bootloader, so you'll have to reinstall it after Windows installation anyhow.

Beware, that Windows 8 (at least the 64bit version) requires your PC to boot using EFI, what might cause troubles if you installed Ubuntu using BIOS emulation (Ubuntu might not boot at any more at all - and I don't know how to fix that).

Comment: I have ext4 . What should I do now?

Comment: I'd use some live CD to shrink the linux partition with the gparted tool. You can either install gparted while runnning the Ubuntu Live CD, or just get the gparted live CD, which is created especially to edit disk partitions. I'm afraid I can't help you after that, because I have zero experience with Windows newer than XP...